# ActiveRecord find when include?() matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Resource model with attribute subcategory_list, which is a comma-separated list of subcategories.  Is it possible to do a find_by_x method (or equivalent) that pulls only those resources that belong to a certain subcategory?

So if given:

```
Resource.create(subcategory_list: "Fun, Games") # resource 1
Resource.create(subcategory_list: "Fun") # resource 2
Resource.create(subcategory_list: "Games") # resource 3
```

I would need a query to get both resources 1 and 2 when my input is "Fun". I can return ONLY "Fun" but not "Fun, Games" with the following

```
Resource.find_all_by_subcategory_list("Fun")
=> resource 2 (but not resource 1)
```

Is there a way to modify this query to include "Fun, Games" as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `subcategory_list` is a comma-seperated string:

```
Resource.where('subcategory_list LIKE ?', "%Fun%")
```

If `subcategory` is an associated model:

```
Resource.joins(:subcategories).where('subcategories.name = ?', "Fun")
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MrTheWalrus, but you might also want to check out [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) by [Michael Bleigh](https://github.com/mbleigh).  It looks like what you are doing is tags associated with Resource and the acts_as_taggable_on gem will add a lot of power without having to write a lot of additional code, including what you are trying to do now as well.

Comment: I'm actually restructuring to eliminate ActsAsTaggableOn, since I don't need all the extra features and want to hit the database as little as possible.  For out of the box functionality and easy set up though, I agree!

Comment: Now it makes sense why you are trying to do that then.  Good to know.  The definitely go with what MrTheWalrus suggested.